# Constructor Reflection is not accepting Map or List parameters even though i have a public constructor with Object as parameter

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

i have a class with constructor overloaded as follows

```
   public LoggingTest(String a) {
        System.out.println("string ");
    }

    public LoggingTest(Object a) {
        System.out.println("object");
    }
    public LoggingTest(String a, Object b) {
        System.out.println("string and object");
    }

    public LoggingTest(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println("string and String");
    }
```

i wanted to dynamically create an instance of LoggingTest class. For that i am using below Constructor reflection code.

Object[] objArray = {obj1, obj2};

```
    if (objArray.length == 1) {
        Constructor<LoggingTest> cons = LoggingTest.class.getConstructor(objArray[0].getClass());
        cons.newInstance(objArray[0]);
    } else if (objArray.length == 2) {  
        Constructor<LoggingTest> cons = LoggingTest.class.getConstructor(objArray[0].getClass(),objArray[1].getClass());
        cons.newInstance(objArray[0], objArray[1]);
    }
```

Here when i pass 
     `Object[] objArray = {"abc", "abc"); //works fine and prints "string and` string" to console

but when i pass

```
 Object[] objArray = {"abc", new ArrayList<String>()); //dint work.
```

expected to print "string and object" to console..but gives an exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.citigroup.digital.ccp.ccs.utils.LoggingTest.<init>(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at com.citigroup.digital.ccp.ccs.utils.LoggingTest.main(LoggingTest.java:42)
```

the same scenario will work if i create another constructor with String and ArrayList as parameters which i dont want to, because i am not sure what is type of the parameter. so i made it as Object.

Any help is greatly apreciated.

Comment: the exception quite clearly states the cause of the error.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for a constructor with signature (String, ArrayList) when you do the following:

```
Constructor<LoggingTest> cons = 
    LoggingTest.class.getConstructor(
        objArray[0].getClass(),objArray[1].getClass());
```

That's because the second element in your array is an ArrayList (you can print objArray[1].getClass() - it will print ArrayList). Since there is no constructor with ArrayList as the second argument, you see the error.

Change the line to:

```
Constructor<LoggingTest> cons = 
    LoggingTest.class.getConstructor(
        String.class, Object.class);
```

That should work.

Comment: i know but i am not sure about the second parameter.. here ArrayList is an example.

one thing if ArrayList is not there.. wont it pick the String, Object constructor

Comment: If you have a (String, Object) constructor, you can avoid the (String, String) constructor all together and do the instanceof String inside the body of the (String, Object) constructor to handle String scenarios conditionally. That's only good idea if you have one or two special cases (like String). Other option is to do what the answer below suggest and make getConstructor() call conditionally based the type of the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

There is of course a way to make this work with reflection, but given the limited number of choices (4), I would prefer writing some if / else blocks and calling the appropriate constructor manually based on what you detect:

```
if(array.length == 2 && array[0] instanceof String && array[1] instanceof String){
    return new MyObject((String)array[0], (String)array[1])
}else if (array.length == 2 && array[0] instanceof String){
    return new MyObject((String)array[0], array[1])
} // etc.
```